# Lost connection to XBox Live

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

When I test my internet connection it says that everything is up and running.

However, when I go to sign in it says that my XBox Live connection has been lost and asks me if I want to test my connection. Even though I am not signed in with any profile it still signs me out when I try to test my connection (even though I did not sign in to the profile).

This is a problem that still persists when I restart the router and don't know what to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried connecting your Xbox 360 directly to your modem, rather than through the router?

Answer (score 2):

Go into your system settings and select storage, then select gamer profiles. If any of these are corrupted then you must delete the profile only and not the data then redownload those profiles onto your xbox. If this is not the case then you might need to delete your system cache: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/settings-and-initial-setup/clear-system-cache

If it still doesn't work then try these steps provided by XBox Live support

1. On your console, go to Settings, and then select System.
2. Select Storage, and then select your primary storage device.
3. Select System Items.
4. Select Marketplace System Data.
5. Select Delete.
6. Restart your console.

If that still doesn't fix the issue then it is most likely a networking issue which you should then try hooking up a laptop or another computer to the same connection in your XBox, as in physically unplug the cord from the XBox and plug it into something else that can use the internet to test if the connection is actually good or not. If it is a wireless connection then you might have to manually enter your network preferences in the XBox Live connection options. For more help on that just contact Xbox Live support and have them guide you through the steps.

I have had many unfortunate times with XBox Live way too many times that I can count.
Hope this helps!